# How to calculate the sum of particular column values in gridview using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am working on a school ERP project as an ASP.NET web application in which we have a gridview. On my page I want to calculate the sum of column values of the gridview but the code which I am using returns two or three times the total of the particular column. Any suggestions on how we can calculate the right total of the particular column?

[image]

Here I use one checkboxlist in which we have the following item

```
Apr-16,May-16,Jun-16,jul-16,Aug-16,Sep-16,Oct-16,Nov-16,Dec-16,Jan-16,Feb-16,Mar-16
```

When we select Apr-16 chekbox from cheboxlist then gridview shows Aprl-16 month fee and when we select Apr-16,May-16 then gridview shows Apr-16,May-16 Fees Details.

When we select May-16,Jun-16,Jul-16 then gridview shows May-16,Jun-16,Jul-16 three fees details.

I want the output like:

[image]

Now I want to calculate the sum of the particular column in my gridview

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace egurkul
{
    [Serializable]
    public class field
    {
        public string duemonth { get; set; }
        public decimal Admission_Fee { get; set; }
        public decimal Prospectus_Registration_Fee { get; set; }
        public decimal Maintenance_Fee { get; set; }
        public decimal Computer_Fee { get; set; }
        public decimal Examination_Fee { get; set; }
        public decimal Tution_Fee { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class feeRecipt : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con;
        string duemonth;
        int i;

        decimal TotalAdmission_Fee, TotalProspectus_Registration_Fee, TotalMaintenance_Fee, TotalComputer_Fee, TotalExamination_Fee, TotalTution_Fee;
        decimal Admission_Fee, Prospectus_Registration_Fee, Maintenance_Fee, Computer_Fee, Examination_Fee, Tution_Fee;

        DataTable dt;
        List<field> data = null; 
        decimal Total = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                getddlclass();
                bindchbxlstduedate();
            }
        }

        public void getddlclass()
        {
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
             con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;

             con.Open();
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from class", con);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             da.Fill(ds);

             ddlclassname.DataSource = ds;
             ddlclassname.DataTextField = "class_name";
             ddlclassname.DataValueField = "class_id";
             ddlclassname.DataBind();
             ddlclassname.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

             con.Close();
        }

        public void bindchbxlstduedate()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                 con = new SqlConnection();
                 con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;

                 con.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                 cmd.Connection = con;

                 cmd.CommandText = "Readduedat";
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while (sdr.Read())
                     {
                         ListItem item = new ListItem();
                         item.Text = sdr["duemonth"].ToString();
                         item.Value = sdr["duedateid"].ToString();
                         chbxlstduedate.Items.Add(item);
                     }
                 }

                 con.Close();
           }
     }

     protected void chbxlstduedate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         for (i = 0; i < chbxlstduedate.Items.Count; i++)
         {
            if (chbxlstduedate.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                duemonth = Convert.ToString(chbxlstduedate.Items[i]);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString;
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "readfeeshead";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duemonth", duemonth);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classname", Convert.ToString(ddlclassname.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feecatename", Convert.ToString(ddlstcategory.SelectedItem));
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                       duemonth1 = sdr["duemonth"].ToString();
                       Admission_Fee1 = sdr["Admission_Fee"].ToString();
                       Prospectus_Registration_Fee1 = sdr["Prospectus_Registration_Fee"].ToString();
                       Maintenance_Fee1 = sdr["Maintenance_Fee"].ToString();
                       Computer_Fee1 = sdr["Computer_Fee"].ToString();
                       Examination_Fee1 =sdr["Examination_Fee"].ToString();
                       Tution_Fee1 = sdr["Tution_Fee"].ToString();

                    }
                }

                con.Close();

                if (data == null)
                    data = new List<field>();

                field f1 = new field();

                f1.duemonth = duemonth1;

                if (Admission_Fee1 == "")
                {
                    f1.Admission_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                   f1.Admission_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(Admission_Fee1);
                }

                if (Prospectus_Registration_Fee1 == "")
                    {
                        f1.Prospectus_Registration_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f1.Prospectus_Registration_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(Prospectus_Registration_Fee1);
                    }
                    if (Maintenance_Fee1 == "")
                    {
                        f1.Maintenance_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f1.Maintenance_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(Maintenance_Fee1);
                    }
                    if (Computer_Fee1 == "")
                    {
                        f1.Computer_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f1.Computer_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(Computer_Fee1);
                    }
                    if (Examination_Fee1 == "")
                    {
                        f1.Examination_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f1.Examination_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(Examination_Fee1);
                    }
                    if (Tution_Fee1 == "")
                    {
                        f1.Tution_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        f1.Tution_Fee = Convert.ToDecimal(Tution_Fee1);
                    }
                    data.Add(f1);
                    ViewState["_data"] = data;
                    GridView1.DataSource = data;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

            }


        }

    }



 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView dtview = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            Label lbladmissionfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbladmissionfee");
            TotalAdmission_Fee = TotalAdmission_Fee + Convert.ToDecimal(lbladmissionfee.Text);

            Label lblcomputerfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblcomputerfee");
            TotalComputer_Fee = TotalComputer_Fee + Convert.ToDecimal(lblcomputerfee.Text);

            Label lblExaminationfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblExaminationfee");
            TotalExamination_Fee = TotalExamination_Fee + Convert.ToDecimal(lblExaminationfee.Text);

            Label lblMaintenancefee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblMaintenancefee");
            TotalMaintenance_Fee = TotalMaintenance_Fee + Convert.ToDecimal(lblMaintenancefee.Text);

            Label lblProsepectusRegistrationFee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProsepectusRegistrationFee");
            TotalProspectus_Registration_Fee = TotalProspectus_Registration_Fee +Convert.ToDecimal(lblProsepectusRegistrationFee.Text);

            Label lblTutionfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTutionfee");
            TotalTution_Fee = TotalTution_Fee + Convert.ToDecimal(lblTutionfee.Text);


        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {

            Label lbl_totaladmissionfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_totaladmissionfee");
            lbl_totaladmissionfee.Text = TotalAdmission_Fee.ToString();

            Label lbl_totalcomputerfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_totalcomputerfee");
            lbl_totalcomputerfee.Text = TotalComputer_Fee.ToString();

            Label lbl_Totalexaminationfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_Totalexaminationfee");
            lbl_Totalexaminationfee.Text = TotalExamination_Fee.ToString();

            Label lbl_totalmaintenancefee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_totalmaintenancefee");
            lbl_totalmaintenancefee.Text = TotalMaintenance_Fee.ToString();

            Label lbl_TotalProsepectusRegistrationFee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_TotalProsepectusRegistrationFee");
            lbl_TotalProsepectusRegistrationFee.Text = TotalProspectus_Registration_Fee.ToString();

            Label lbl_Totaltutionfee = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_Totaltutionfee");
            lbl_Totaltutionfee.Text = TotalTution_Fee.ToString();



            decimal alltotal = TotalTution_Fee + TotalProspectus_Registration_Fee + TotalMaintenance_Fee + TotalExamination_Fee + TotalComputer_Fee + TotalAdmission_Fee;
            Label lbl_Totalsamount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_Totalsamount");
            lbl_Totalsamount.Text = alltotal.ToString();



        }


    }
```

Comment: Approach looks fine.  I think you may have some copy/paste issues in code.  Look at where you are summing registration fee.  It is adding the lblMaintenancefee instead of lblProsepectusRegistrationFee.  Also, I'd think you would want computer fee here instead of admission... TotalComputer_Fee = TotalComputer_Fee + Convert.ToDecimal(lbladmissionfee.Text);

Comment: Dear Burgundy thanks for your reply , I update my code but i  did not get my desired result  I Still get same result as shown in my first image not second image result I want result like second image please go through.

Comment: let me explain my updated code give two times of sum of particular column   when we add two rows value for apr-16 month 1500 and 0 for may-16 month  for column Admission Fee then my desired result is 1500+0 =1500 but my code give result 3000 i did not understand where i have fault in my code please let me know

Comment: I can't really tell where your variables are coming from.  Are you using the same variable throughout the whole page life cycle for your fee totals?  If so, you are setting them in the SelectIndexChanged event and then adding to it again in the RowDataBound event.  For instance, the variable TotalAdmission_Fee is being set when you change index.  Then you are adding on top of it.  Try using a separate variable for the grid.

Comment: This is just a wall of code without any hint where to look an why it apparently doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm in hurry for office

try this code

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dvData.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
label.text = sum.ToString();
```

let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks Ahsan Aziz where I put this code within RowDataBound event or else where

Comment: You can place this code where you wanted to calculate sum and set the result to label. The minor things to be observed are Cells[any number] indicates column number. That code should work. @user2342574

Comment: i am using web application not windows application so here not dataGridView1 thre is GridView1 and when we use GridView1 i have seen an error   Error 3 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\ERP egurkul\egurkul\egurkul\feeRecipt.aspx.cs 226 79 egurkul

Comment: @AAhsan Aziz Abbasi Thanks and its still working for me.

Answer (score -1):

**I'm Sure you agree with below code I personally try this in my Live Project:**

```
double sum = 0.00;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   sum = sum + Convert.ToDouble(dr.ItemArray[6]);
}
txtGrandTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Essentially repeats the other answer.